# Retrieve all nodes where attributes contain a given string

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I want to retrieve all the RULE nodes that have one or more attributes that contains a given string. Once i found them I need to replace the string with a new one.
I tested those XPath query but they do not work:

```
string xpathquery = "/FIREWALL/ETH/RULE[contains(@*,'" + toTest + "')]"; //DOES NOT WORK
string xpathquery = "/FIREWALL/ETH/RULE[contains(attribute::*,'" + toTest +"')]"; //DOES NOT WORK
```

The strange thing is that if I use @attributename or attribute::attributename it actually works. Where is the error?

I am using the contains function because there could be two different cases, let's say I want to replace $HOST1 with $HOST2:

```
<RULE .... host="$HOST1"/> //NO PROBLEM
<RULE .... host="$HOST1:21"/> //I NEED TO REPLACE ONLY $HOST1, NOT THE ENTIRE STRING
```

I can't just set the Value attribute of XmlNode but I need to modify the string. Actually I don't know if XPath can handle this with a find and replace or something like this.

Comment: Do you *definitely* want to use XPath for this? Personally I'd use LINQ to XML directly, but obviously it's your call...

Comment: Well if there's an easier solution with LINQ... Keep in mind I've never used it but I can learn :) For what I could have seen it looks like a query language similar to SQL, am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query you're using checks the concatenated text of all the attributes. The correct syntax is:

```
string xpathquery = "/FIREWALL/ETH/RULE/@*[contains(.,'" + toTest + "')]/..";
```

In other words, find a matching attribute and return its parent element. Of course, if what you want to do is to work with the attribute values, you can dispense with the `/..` on the end, in which case you'll be returned the actual attribute nodes and can just iterate through them modifying the values accordingly.

Comment: Or equivalently, /FILEWALL/ETH/RULE[@*[contains(.,' + toTest + "')]]". But note also, constructing XPath expressions by string concatenation is a bad habit because it leaves you open to injection attacks. It's better to use a variable and to bind the variable from the calling API, if the API you are using allows that.

Comment: You wrote: *The query you're using checks the concatenated text of all the attributes* **That's wrong**. And the problem is in fact the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

The standard XPath function `contains()` requires a single string as its first argument. When the first argument is a list of nodes (as in your case), only the string value of the first node in the provided node-set is used. This is how you get your current results.

**Solution**:

```
/FIREWALL/ETH/RULE/@*[contains(.,' + toTest + ')]
```